# How to write a sql query to find maximum weekly working hours?

Tags: mysql

I am accessing a Company's Database trying to help the HR to forward the Ace of the
Week details for rewarding purposes.
The “Gate_Logs” table has the below columns.

a. Employee ID - A 4 Digit unique Number assigned to every employee.

b. Status – In or Out

c. Timestamp – Recorded timestamp

The “Employee” Table has

a. Employee ID

b. Level

c. Designation

d. Joining Date

e. Reporting Location

f. Reporting Location ID - Single Digit ID

Write a SQL query to select the employees with highest weekly work time over the past year across it's different locations.

Comment: Please add some formatting to your question to make it easier to read. Including the CREATE TABLE statements for the two tables will help, as will including the desired output. Which version of MySQL are you using, as this impacts the functionality available? Can users clock in and out multiple times in one day? Can a user clock in on one day and out on a later day? Are you looking for the user with most time worked for each week for the last year?

Comment: I have formatted the new table

Comment: I can see that you have added a few line breaks which does make it a little easier to read but you have not added any of the other details. If you want people on here to help you (for free) you need to start by helping yourself. Please remove your (non) answer below.

Answer (score 0):

To provide the best solution to this problem we need to know more details but below is a crude solution based on the following assumptions -

1. Your `Timestamp` column contains UNIX TIMESTAMP values not DATETIME values
2. Weeks run from Monday to Sunday
3. For each user within a given week, 'In' and 'Out' records will be in pairs, without overlap and the first record in the period must be an 'In' and the last an 'Out'

```sql
SELECT
    Employees.`ReportingLocation`,
    `employee_hours_per_week`.*
FROM (
    SELECT
        WEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(`Timestamp`), 1) AS `week_no`,
        `EmployeeID`,
        SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(IF(`Status` = 'Out', `Timestamp`, 0)) - SUM(IF(`Status` = 'In', `Timestamp`, 0))) AS `time_worked`
    FROM `Gate_logs`
    WHERE `Timestamp` BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2020-01-06 00:00:00') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2021-01-03 23:59:59')
    GROUP BY `week_no`, `EmployeeID`
) AS `employee_hours_per_week`
INNER JOIN `Employees` USING (`EmployeeID`)
ORDER BY
    `Employees`.`ReportingLocation` ASC,
    `employee_hours_per_week`.`week_no` ASC,
    `employee_hours_per_week`.`time_worked` DESC
```